# Add standby database on different OS version?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, standby, oracle-grid-control

Primary database is installed on RHEL 6.1. Standby database software is installed on RHEL 7.0. I am trying to add new standby database by using Grid Control. Database versions are same 11.0.2.0.3.
[image: Below error shows up.]

I was able to add standby database on RHEL 6.1 using same method.

I used the following [link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/oracle-db-11gr2-installation-on-oracle-linux-7) to install ORACLE on RHEL 7.0. Does it have anything to do with oracle group gid is different than RHEL 6.1? On RHEL 7.0, I used oinstall(54321) dba(54322) oper(54323) for gids. On RHEL 6.1, I used oinstall(501) dba(502) oper(503). If it doesnt matter, what should i do?

Comment: 11.2.0.3 is not supported on RHEL 7. Version 11.2.0.4 is the only release in the 11.2 branch that is.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by executing root.sh file in the AGENT_HOME folder. I think it was permission issue, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The guid and uid must match on both systems as well as any user folder permission privileges. Otherwise you will have issues like you describe.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. It might be even more helpful if you could describe why this works and how it would help